# Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked

Tags: angular

In my angular component i have following code for date picker -

```
this.convertTodate(Response.json().details['expiry_date']);

convertTodate(val)
{
  let newdate = new Date(val);
  const day = newdate.getDate();
  const month = newdate.getMonth() + 1;
  const year = newdate.getFullYear();
  let completedate = `${year}-${this.pad(month)}-${this.pad(day)}`;
  return completedate;
}

pad(n)
{
  return (n < 10) ? ("0" + n) : n;
}
```

---

When i pass this date to webservice. it comes up with following error -

Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: '2017-10-19'. Current value: '1508371200000'.

Comment: it's a known issue see github https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17572 and https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18970

Comment: @TouqeerShafi. it's not an issue, it's by design, read [Everything you need to know about the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4)

Comment: Yup i agree @AngularInDepth.com, but most of the people think it's a bug because it was not reproducible in angular 4.3 i think.

Comment: @TouqeerShafi, it's by design from the beginning, since Angular enforces one-way data flow

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com see this: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17572#issuecomment-309364246 although you are right that it's by design but it was not reproducible in angular 4.1.3

Comment: @TouqeerShafi, maybe it wasn't reproduced *under this particular use case*, but the check and the implementation were there in the beginning

Comment: np i don't think so because i got a project which i migrated from angularjs to angular 2 then angular 4, but then it was not producible until angular 4.1.3, after when angular was updated to angular 4.2, although this does not change any thing. by now you are right it's by design.